# OpenAI Gym - Env.Render() function returning "Display surface quit"

Tags: jupyter-notebook, render, openai-gym

[A screenshot of my code with error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eatcI.png)

I am following the tutorial seen at https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7SVv07QXO5M&ab_channel=HackersRealm
The exact code I am following is here: https://github.com/aswintechguy/Reinforcement-Learning-Projects/blob/main/Cartpole%20Balance%20-%20OpenAI%20Gym%20-%20Reinforcement%20Learning/CartPole%20Balance%20-%20OpenAI%20Gym%20-%20Reinforcement%20Learning.ipynb

Not sure what I am doing wrong but the guy doing the tutorial had no issues so I'm not sure how to troubleshoot this. I'm also doing this in a Jupyter Notebook. Any ideas what I might be doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

I have seen similar error, in my case i got this error when i ran the env.close() and tried running again, i'm suspecting, this was the reason for my error, because once env.close() has been called there is no environment to perform rest of the operations so I had to re-run the cell to create the environment to try it again. Im assuming this may have been your case.

Try running the cell with make environment and retry the cell which throws u the error.

Comment: This appears to be more of a comment and hopeful suggestion than a tested answer.